# Training Word2Vec Model from sourced data - Issue Tokenizing data

Tags: python, pandas, tokenize, word2vec

I have recently sourced and curated a lot of reddit data from Google Bigquery.

The dataset looks like this:

[image: Data Preview]

Before passing this data to word2vec to create a vocabulary and be trained, it is required that I properly tokenize the 'body_cleaned' column.

I have attempted the tokenization with both manually created functions and NLTK's word_tokenize, but for now I'll keep it focused on using word_tokenize.

Because my dataset is rather large, close to 12 million rows, it is impossible for me to open and perform functions on the dataset in one go. Pandas tries to load everything to RAM and as you can understand it crashes, even on a system with 24GB of ram.

I am facing the following issue:

- When I tokenize the dataset (using NTLK word_tokenize), if I perform the function on the dataset as a whole, it correctly tokenizes and word2vec accepts that input and learns/outputs words correctly in its vocabulary.
- When I tokenize the dataset by first batching the dataframe and iterating through it, the resulting token column is not what word2vec prefers; although word2vec trains its model on the data gathered for over 4 hours, the resulting vocabulary it has learnt consists of single characters in several encodings, as well as emojis - not words.

To troubleshoot this, I created a tiny subset of my data and tried to perform the tokenization on that data in two different ways:

- Knowing that my computer can handle performing the action on the dataset, I simply did:

```
reddit_subset = reddit_data[:50]

reddit_subset['tokens'] = reddit_subset['body_cleaned'].apply(lambda x: word_tokenize(x))
```

This produces the following result:
[image: Tokenized Data Preview]

This in fact works with word2vec and produces model one can work with. Great so far.

Because of my inability to operate on such a large dataset in one go, I had to get creative with how I handle this dataset. My solution was to batch the dataset and work on it in small iterations using Panda's own batchsize argument.

I wrote the following function to achieve that:

```
def reddit_data_cleaning(filepath, batchsize=20000):
    if batchsize:
        df = pd.read_csv(filepath, encoding='utf-8', error_bad_lines=False, chunksize=batchsize, iterator=True, lineterminator='\n')
    print("Beginning the data cleaning process!")
    start_time = time.time()
    flag = 1
    chunk_num = 1
    for chunk in df:
        chunk[u'tokens'] = chunk[u'body_cleaned'].apply(lambda x: word_tokenize(x))
        chunk_num += 1
    if flag == 1:
            chunk.dropna(how='any')
            chunk = chunk[chunk['body_cleaned'] != 'deleted']
            chunk = chunk[chunk['body_cleaned'] != 'removed']
            print("Beginning writing a new file")
            chunk.to_csv(str(filepath[:-4] + '_tokenized.csv'), mode='w+', index=None, header=True)
            flag = 0
        else:
            chunk.dropna(how='any')
            chunk = chunk[chunk['body_cleaned'] != 'deleted']
            chunk = chunk[chunk['body_cleaned'] != 'removed']
            print("Adding a chunk into an already existing file")
            chunk.to_csv(str(filepath[:-4] + '_tokenized.csv'), mode='a', index=None, header=None)
    end_time = time.time()
    print("Processing has been completed in: ", (end_time - start_time), " seconds.")
```

Although this piece of code allows me to actually work through this huge dataset in chunks and produces results where otherwise I'd crash from memory failures, I get a result which doesn't fit my word2vec requirements, and leaves me quite baffled at the reason for it.

I used the above function to perform the same operation on the Data subset to compare how the result differs between the two functions, and got the following:

[image: Comparison of Methods]

The desired result is on the new_tokens column, and the function that chunks the dataframe produces the "tokens" column result.

Is anyone any wiser to help me understand why the same function to tokenize produces a wholly different result depending on how I iterate over the dataframe?

I appreciate you if you read through the whole issue and stuck through!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking gojomo's advice I simplified my approach at reading the csv file and writing to a text file.

My initial approach using pandas had yielded some pretty bad processing times for a file with around 12 million rows, and memory issues due to how pandas reads data all into memory before writing it out to a file.

What I also realized was that I had a major flaw in my previous code.
I was printing some output (as a sanity check), and because I printed output too often, I overflowed Jupyter and crashed the notebook, not allowing the underlying and most important task to complete.

I got rid of that, simplified reading with the csv module and writing into a txt file, and I processed the reddit database of ~12 million rows in less than 10 seconds.

Maybe not the finest piece of code, but I was scrambling to solve an issue that stood as a roadblock for me for a couple of days (and not realizing that part of my problem was my sanity checks crashing Jupyter was an even bigger frustration).

```
def generate_corpus_txt(csv_filepath, output_filepath):
    import csv
    import time
    start_time = time.time()
    with open(csv_filepath, encoding = 'utf-8') as csvfile:
        datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        count = 0
        header = next(csvfile)
        print(time.asctime(time.localtime()), " ---- Beginning Processing")
        with open(output_filepath, 'w+') as output:
            # Check file as empty
            if header != None:
                for row in datareader:
                        # Iterate over each row after the header in the csv
                        # row variable is a list that represents a row in csv
                    processed_row = str(' '.join(row)) + '\n'
                    output.write(processed_row)
                    count += 1
                    if count == 1000000:
                        print(time.asctime(time.localtime()), " ---- Processed 1,000,000 Rows of data.")
                        count = 0
    print('Processing took:', int((time.time()-start_time)/60), ' minutes')
    output.close()
    csvfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

First & foremost, beyond a certain size of data, & especially when working with raw text or *tokenized* text, you probably *don't* want to be using Pandas dataframes for every interim result.

They add extra overhead & complication that isn't fully 'Pythonic'. This is particularly the case for:

- Python `list` objects where each word is a separate string: once you've tokenized raw strings into this format, as for example to feed such texts to Gensim's `Word2Vec` model, trying to put those into Pandas just leads to confusing list-representation issues (as with your columns where the same text might be shown as either `['yessir', 'shit', 'is', 'real']` – which is a true Python list literal – or  `[yessir, shit, is, real]` – which is some other mess likely to break if any tokens have challenging characters).
- the raw word-vectors (or later, text-vectors): these are more compact & natural/efficient to work with in raw Numpy arrays than Dataframes

So, by all means, if Pandas helps for loading or other non-text fields, use it there. But then use more fundamntal Python or Numpy datatypes for tokenized text & vectors - perhaps using some field (like a unique ID) in your Dataframe to correlate the two.

Especially for large text corpuses, it's more typical to get away from CSV and instead use large text files, with one text per newline-separated line, and any each line being pre-tokenized so that spaces can be fully trusted as token-separated.

That is: even if your initial text data has more complicated punctuation-sensative tokenization, or other preprocessing that combines/changes/splits other tokens, try to *do that just once* (especially if it involves costly regexes), writing the results to a single simple text file which then fits the simple rules: read one text per line, split each line only by spaces.

Lots of algorithms, like Gensim's `Word2Vec` or `FastText`, can either stream such files directly or via very low-overhead iterable-wrappers - so the text is *never* completely in memory, only read as needed, repeatedly, for multiple training iterations.

For more details on this efficient way to work with large bodies of text, see this artice: https://rare-technologies.com/data-streaming-in-python-generators-iterators-iterables/

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment; it was highly informative and made me see that I need to explore other means by which to achieve my goal outside of Pandas.

I am also in the process of reading through the article you sent me and I'll get right on applying your wisdom. I may come back with questions, but you've definitely put me on a path where I see more possible solutions.

Comment: I've been researching ways to write from a pandas file (or a large csv) to a text file.

Is there any specific method you would particularly advise I go for?

For example, with open(txt) and write into that, or use pandas_to_string() method, or even use numpy and get the numpy.values into a text file?

I'd like to understand what method is most ideal for such a large dataset.

Comment: (OR should I keep using the way I have so far of batching through my pandas dataset and write the output of the chunk into a txt file?)

Comment: If you can easily read your whole CSV source data into a single Pandas Dataframe, sure, do that, then iterate over the texts, streaming the tokenized text to a new plain text-file. But if you don't need Pandas or other things, you could just read the CSV file yourself, line-by-line, ignoring the irrelevant parts, tokenizing important text, writing it to a separate file. These are basic text file IO operations in Python, usually just a few to a couple dozen lines of code - but best attempted after you review some other file IO examples, and if you hit problems, asked as specific separate Qs.

Comment: I went ahead and used the CSV package to iterate over the rows and write them onto a txt file. Thank you for your help!
It was a bit challenging in the beginning because I was using jupyter and because I was asking the function to print some output (for my sanity) I managed to overload the system with output and crash it. Less output, more writing, solved my problem.

Comment: You're welcome! I could see you'd given it a lot of effort but needed to move a bit more in the streaming/plain-Python/plain-files direction.

Comment: Looking back to how much time I "wasted" trying to come up with "clever" solutions, when I took your advice to simplify things and then eliminated the print output of the function (that was more of a jupyter hiccup), I was so surprised to see that the 12 million row csv was processed in less than a minute. Couldn't have asked for more than such guidance, again kudos my friend.

Comment: Edited OP to include my solution, once again thanks.

Comment: @Dkoded I rejected your edit. Please write up your own answer (which you can then mark as the accepted answer, nothing wrong with that) instead of editing the solution into existing answers. Literally just copy pasting what you tried to edit in into a new answer would be fine.

Comment: Even though putting the asker's solution as a separate answer is best, I wish I could see what @Dkoded had wrote in the proposed-edit!

Comment: Hadn't seen that update. I've updated a post with my answer. Thank you guys